# Does Apache Camel xslt component support schema aware xslt processing

Tags: xslt, apache-camel, saxon

I am trying to use saxon for xslt processing in apache camel. I also want to use SchemaAwareTransformer which is part of licensed version of saxon. For this, I set transformerFactoryClass = com.saxonica.SchemaAwareTransformerFactory (Licensed version 9.0.0.5).

Now in the xslt,

1. I import the schema like

```xml
<xsl:import-schema namespace="http://defiml.TctML_col_v1" />
```

2. declare namespace in stylesheet declaration

```xml
xmlns:tct_col="http://defiml.TctML_col_v1"
```

3. define the template match like

```xml
<xsl:template match="element(*,tct_col:TCT_CollateralStock)" as="element(*, defiml:DL_CollateralService)">
  . . .
</xsl:template>
```

But when I run, I get the error

No schema for this namespace is known, and no schema-location was supplied, so no schema has been imported; SystemID: ; Line#: 19; Column#: -1

Is there a mechanism to provide xslt component all the xsd schema used for this transformation ?

Comment: Don't you need a `schema-location` attribute on your `xsl:import-schema`, to tell the XSLT processor the location of the schema you want to import?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I tried schema-location like this <xsl:import-schema namespace="http://defiml.TctML_col_v1" schema-location="Tomcat/TctML_col.xsd" />
<xsl:import-schema namespace="http://defiml.somexService.V3_40" schema-location="DefiML.xsd"/>.  TctML_col.xsd seems to work because it is a single xsd.

Comment: But DefiML.xsd has lot of references to other schema which is causing an error "Module null includes itself recursively; SystemID: ; Line#: 3; Column#: -1. Module null includes itself recursively; SystemID: ; Line#: 4; Column#: -1. ... Line#: 8; Column#: -1. Then I get an error "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: There is no type named defiml:DL_CollateralService in an imported schema

Comment: Seems like the question has moved on. You've established that Apache Camel can load schema-aware Saxon, you've solved the problem of locating the schema. The warnings about the schema including itself can probably be ignored; though the fact that it says "Module null" is a bit more worrying because it suggests that the base URI / system ID of the schema module is not known. I would do some experiments to see if the code works when you take Apache Camel out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, the comment thread shows that the answer to your original question is "yes": you have demonstrated that a schema-aware transformation (using Saxon) can be invoked from a Camel environment.